# Using @staticmethod wrapper for magic method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

In one of my child classes, I want to override the parent's `__iter__` with:

```
def __iter__(self):
    yield from ()
```

however, because I'm not referencing `self` in `__iter__`, would it be pythonic / acceptable to write:

```
@staticmethod
def __iter__():
    yield from ()
```

Comment: No, it would be weird and pointless.

Comment: Are ever planning to use it without a reference to a class instance?

Comment: @wim thank you, I'll omit it.

Comment: For example, check the Google Python style guide, which recommends to avoid using `staticmethods` in general: https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html

Comment: @pavel, good point - no. So it doesn't make sense to add the decorator. Thanks for the comment

Comment: No, this would be  very strange